# платежи на площадке

Tags: алгоритм

Мы разрабатывам сайт, на котором хотели бы размещать обьявления от разных людей по продаже БУ вещей, как мы можем добавить функцию оплаты товаров на сайте с помощью paypal аналогично Ebay например?

Comment: Изучаете API paypal и реализуете работу по нему. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/

Comment: Можно использовать PayPal API. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/